# Не работает базовый метод строки и поиск по строке регулярным выражением

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-2.x

Есть очень примитивный код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
from string import *

text = 'тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер'
text = text.lower()
#text = text.decode('utf-8')
print text

model_list = ['туссан', 'туарег', 'королла', 'нексия']

for model in model_list:
    response = re.search(model, text, re.IGNORECASE)
    if response:
        print 'найдено: ' + response.group(0)
```

Задача простая - есть список моделей и есть строка текста, по каждой модели списка надо найти вхождение в строку, и вот тут-то проблема:

1. данный код в том виде как выше в консоли пишет

   > тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер
   >
   > найдено: туарег

а должен найти явно два авто

2. если задать переменную так `text = u'тот же самый текст ...'` или строку `text = text.lower()` переписать как `text = text.decode('utf-8').lower()`, то тогда в консоли уже следующее:

   > тут будет внедорожник (туссан, туарег) или ровер

т.е. регистр стал нижним, но при этом поиск не происходит. Более того, не понятно, почему `re.I` (или `re.IGNORECASE`) вообще не работает. Пробовал дописать `re.I|re.U|re.S|re.M`, ничего не выходит.

В чем тут проблема? Мне всего лишь надо проверить несколько слов в куске текста, при этом без учета регистра.

Comment: Рискну предположить что if (model in text) будет работать так как надо. И что если text.decode, то и model.decode надо делать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да, **if model in text** также работает, но он работает со строкой, которая по-прежнему не переведна в нижний регистр, а значит снова я не нахожу в ней Туарег

Comment: Да, in регистрозависим. in text.lower() попробуйте

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов,  in text.lower() не помог(

Comment: @СтаниславАвзалов я обновил ответ. Возможно, теперь вам будет удобно использовать другой способ. В любом случае, альтернативы знать полезно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в кодировке. Вы можете решить её несколькими способами (отсортированно по моему субъективному восприятию удобства способов):

1. Перейти на Python 3

   В Python 3 по умолчанию используются юникодные литералы, поэтому у вас не возникнет подобных проблем. В коде при этом достаточно использовать функцию `print` вместо оператора, т.е. добавить скобки вызова функции:

   ```
   import re

   text = 'тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер'
   model_list = ['туссан', 'туарег', 'королла', 'нексия']

   for model in model_list:
       response = re.search(model, text, re.IGNORECASE)
       if response:
           print('найдено: ' + response.group(0))
   ```

   Заметьте также, что нам нет необходимости в Python 3 вручную указывать кодировку файла исходного кода: в Python 3 по умолчанию используется кодировка utf-8.
2. Вставить в начале файла строку

   ```
   from __future__ import unicode_literals
   ```

   Эта строка говорит, что в файле все строковые литералы будут иметь тип `unicode`. Особенно удобно использовать эту возможность для того, чтобы писать переносимый между версиями Python код (в сочетании с остальными возможностями модуля `__future__`). Выглядеть это будет следующим образом:

   ```
   # coding: utf-8

   from __future__ import unicode_literals
   import re

   text = 'тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер'
   model_list = ['туссан', 'туарег', 'королла', 'нексия']

   for model in model_list:
       response = re.search(model, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
       if response:
           print 'найдено: ' + response.group(0)
   ```
3. Преобразовать используемые строки в юникод. Так вышло, модуль регулярных выражений некорректно обрабатывает кириллицу в байтовых строках (не умеет искать без учёта регистра). Вы можете вызвать преобразование в юникодные строки для нужных переменных:

   ```
   # coding: utf-8

   import re

   text = 'тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер'
   model_list = ['туссан', 'туарег', 'королла', 'нексия']

   text = text.decode('utf-8')

   for model in model_list:
       model = model.decode('utf-8')
       response = re.search(model, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
       if response:
           print u'найдено: ' + response.group(0)
   ```

Заметьте, что при выводе результата, строка `u'найдено'` помечена юникодной. Это важно, потому что складывать можно только строки одного типа, а `response.group(0)` возвращает нам юникодную строку.

4. Использовать юникодные литералы вручную:  *(бывший способ №3)*

   ```
   # coding: utf-8

   import re

   text = u'тут будет внедорожник (Туссан, туарег) или Ровер'
   model_list = [u'туссан', u'туарег', u'королла', u'нексия']

   for model in model_list:
       response = re.search(model, text, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE)
       if response:
           print u'найдено: ' + response.group(0)
   ```

---

Важно заметить, что при правильном учёте кодировок строк можно пользоваться поиском без учёта регистра, но необходимо добавить флаг `re.UNICODE` для того, чтобы модуль правильно отрабатывал на юникодных строках.

Также старайтесь в новых проектах использовать Python 3, если нет строгих требований использовать версию Python 2.

Comment: Тимофей, третий пункт помог, спасибо вам!

Comment: @СтаниславАвзалов: 3-ий пункт -- это извращение -- не нужно так делать. Если строки указаны прямо в исходном коде, то следует сразу Юникодные константы использовать как показано в 4-ом, 2-ом пунктах. Если текст извне приходит, например, из файла, то можно его в Юникод преобразовать используя `io.open()` (используется по умолчанию в Питон 3) c явным указанием кодировки, если необходимо. Применение `.decode()` оправдано, если нельзя данные в виде  текста сразу получить, а доступны только байты в указанной кодировке.

Comment: @jfs Вы не совсем правильно поняли. В ответ было внесено изменение, Напротив четвёртого пункта указано, что это бывший пункт №3.

Comment: Для ясности: **не** нужно делать: `text.decode(source_code_encoding)`. *Вместо* этого можно делать: `text = dynamic_bytestring.decode(encoding)` или `text = u'..'` или `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, чтобы `'..'` константы создавали Юникодные строки (по умолчанию в Питон 3) или (для динамических строк) использовать api, которое сразу Юникодные строки возвращает.

Comment: Коллеги, попробовал разные варианты, наиболее приемлемым для проекта вижу №2 from __future__ import unicode_literals, минимум изменений кода + он переносимый